# Is there a way to use `dplyr` select helper functions in mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

For example, I have a data frame where I want to get the sum of all columns beginning with "Q3", I could type out each one, but it would be great to be able to do something like this:

```
#Example data
test <- structure(list(UserID = c("53017366", "53017366"), Q3_1 = c(3L, 
3L), Q3_2 = c(2L, 2L), Q3_3 = c(3L, 3L), Q3_4 = c(NA, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L), .Names = c("UserID", "Q3_1", "Q3_2", "Q3_3", "Q3_4"))

#what I'd like to see, but doesn't work
test %>% mutate(total = sum(starts_with("Q3"), na.rm = TRUE))

#What I'd like to end up with:
    UserID Q3_1 Q3_2 Q3_3 Q3_4 total
1 53017366    3    2    3   NA     8
2 53017366    3    2    3    5    13
```

One option suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23222816/5623577) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28745981/5623577) requires putting an entire new select column in the data and using a rowwise function (like rowSums).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rowSums`

```
test %>% 
     mutate(total = rowSums(.[grep("Q3", names(.))], na.rm =TRUE))
#    UserID Q3_1 Q3_2 Q3_3 Q3_4 total
#1 53017366    3    2    3   NA     8
#2 53017366    3    2    3    5    13
```

Comment: Something like this, derived from your answer, works too. Thanks: `test %>% mutate(total = rowSums(.[starts_with("Q3", vars = names(.))], na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: And in this case I am thinking about overall scores and some subscales (though I'm not sure what I'll use). I can add a `[1:3]` to the selection to subset things easily. It seems like a pretty easy way to do it, but if there's a better way I'd be interested in learning.

Answer (score 2):

For this case you can use `janitor::add_totals_col`:

```
library(janitor)
test %>%
  add_totals_col()
#>     UserID Q3_1 Q3_2 Q3_3 Q3_4 Total
#> 1 53017366    3    2    3   NA     8
#> 2 53017366    3    2    3    5    13
```

To your deeper question about needing to use `select` helpers in mutate here, this need can indicate an underlying lack of [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) structure.  In this case you have values in column headers.  In a longer tidy format, say with a variable `quarter`, you could do this elegantly with `group_by` and `summarise`.

Comment: Didn't know that function.  Thanks for providing it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is a small part of survey data, so the columns are different questions. It keeps going with Q3_5, and so on, but eventually hits Q4_1, Q4_2, ... Having a long data set like that is unintuitive to me, but I guess it could include a column for the question set and one for what question it was, then the value.